# Travis not creating android test intermediates folder

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing, travis-ci

I have set up travis and robolectric for android testing. All my test were working fine on both local machine and travis. But I had to add test were I had to use android assets folder under test folder. 
However for this my test are failing on travis but running perfectly well on my local machine.
I had pinpointed the reason being `test-> assets` folder not being created on travis server.

My the `build->intermediates` folder on local machine is like

```
|__build
||__intermediates
|||__app
||||__debug
|||__test
||||__app
|||||__debug
```

However on the travis server `build->intermediates` folder is like

```
|__build
||__intermediates
|||__app
||||__debug
```

Its missing `build->intermediates->test` folder.

What could be the reason for this? How to fix it?

Comment: Is this directory created as part of the build?

Comment: @roidrage yes this is created for tests.

Comment: Do you have a link to a build and an outline of the commands that need to be run to create this directory?

Comment: @roidrage I was able to run mys tests. There was a problem with my script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to run test which were using `test-> assets` folder by changing my script.

The issue was that all other tests ran without running `gradle assembleTest` task . Running them with just `gradle testAppDebug` would work.

But for using `test/assets` I had to modify my test script to

```
./gradlew clean
./gradlew assembleTest
./gradlew test --info
```

And it all worked well.